# How can I stop my Windows console application triggers beeps when displaying binary data

Tags: c++, audio, console-application, beep

I wrote a windows console application that receives binary data from a third party provider. 
For Debug and logging purposes, I display the binary data on the output (the console).

Unfortunately when the character 7 is displayed it triggers a beep. 
Here is a code that can trigger it:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char c = 7;
  std::cout << c;
}
```

My question is simple, is there a way to disable the beeps ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could unplug the beeper in your computer.

If that is not an option:
If you have a method debug(String s) that outputs the string s, you could replace character 7 by something else to avoid the beep.

Another way would be to output the text in hexadecimal form.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, disabling the beeper works, but do you know what the character 7 represents and why does it beep ?

Comment: Character 7 represents a beep.  I'm not kidding.

Comment: In the ASCII encoding scheme, 0x07 represents the BEL control character.  Terminals and output devices usually create a sound (beep) when receiving this character.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of other values that will trigger weird things (depending on what terminal you use). You should check each char with `isprint` before outputting it. Better yet is a function like:

```
void memdump( std::ostream& o, const void* data, size_t len )
{
        const unsigned char* ptr = static_cast<const unsigned char*>(data);

        for( size_t i = 0; i < len; i += 16 )
        {
                o << std::setw(8);
                o << std::setfill('0');
                o << std::hex << i << ' ';
                size_t to = std::min(len,i+16);
                for( size_t j = i; j < to; ++j )
                {
                        o << ' ';
                        o << std::setw(2);
                        o << std::setfill('0');
                        o << std::hex;
                        o << (unsigned)ptr[j];

                        if( (j+1) % 8 == 0 )
                        {
                                o << ' ';
                        }
                }
                o << "  ";
                for( size_t j = to; j < i+16; ++j )
                {
                        o << "   ";
                        if( (j+1) % 8 == 0 )
                        {
                                o << ' ';
                        }
                }

                for( size_t j = i; j < to; ++j )
                {
                        if(isprint(ptr[j]))
                        {
                                o << ptr[j];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                o << '.';
                        }
                        if( (j+1) % 8 == 0 )
                        {
                                o << ' ';
                        }
                }
                o << '\n';
        }
        o << std::dec;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to disable the beeper (at a Windows command line):

```
net stop beep
```

It should disable beeps temporarily. If you want the full effect (re-applies on reboot) type this:

```
sc config beep start= disabled
```

Comment: That's like setting fire to your house because you receive paper spam in your mailbox.

Comment: @CodeCaster Disconnecting the speakers (top voted answer) is much more like that.

Answer (score 0):

`char c = 7;` is a BELL according to ASCII
if you want to display the 7 then you need to wrap it in single quotations marks (or how they are called:

```
char c = '7';
```

If you don't want to display a 7 then you need to remove the character 0x07 or replace it with (for example with '')
(http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: I think the OP wanted to know how to output the character 0x07 without beeping. Not the digit '7'.

Comment: In that case he should remove the char 0x07 or replace it with a ''

Answer (score 0):

Select a code page that interprets the character 7 as a glyph instead of a control character. See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14783921/39590) for details.