# Why does my system beep when writing to Console

Tags: c#, console

I am writing a console tester for a web service that I am using in my app.  When I write the output to my console(JSON) for a large enough set the console app spins and I start getting a beeping noise for 5-10 seconds.  I checked the output for a \a and couldn't find one, so I'm not sure what is causing the beeping.

At this point I am just guessing the long output, but I am unsure what else the problem could be or if there are any solutions.

Comment: Had a similar issue where if the size of the output exceeded the line buffer on the console it would beep at me. Have you tried adjusting the vertical buffer size?

Comment: @lukiffer what would I set the BufferHeight to?

Comment: Depends on the size of your output. Enough vertical lines to display the output... I ended up having to chunk the data and into separate Console.Write() calls.

Comment: That might be the best call for me, since the data will be quite variable in length and could be in the tens of thousands of lines range...

Comment: @lukiffer one of the strings that I am trying to print out is 245345
characters long.  What is a safe char count to break into separate write calls?

Comment: Try something like `var length = (Console.BufferHeight * Console.BufferWidth) / 2;` If there are a lot of newlines, you may have to tweak the divisor.

Comment: @lukiffer I lopped through the string printing every 10000 characters, and I am still getting the beeping.  That would point to a content issue then, right?  Do I need to pause before each iteration?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13973/discussion-between-lukiffer-and-stefan-h)

Answer (score 0):

Could be BEL?

ctl-G

7

7

BEL

BELL

A control character that is used when there is a need to call for attention; it may control alarm or attention devices.

Comment: He said there is no sign of `\a` in the console output. `\a` is the escape sequence for `BEL`.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar when trying to write to a Event Log, but it is full.

Try `Start > Run... > eventvwr` then either clearing out some logs or changing the maximum size of logs (via the 'Action' menu).

Answer (score 0):

Even if you check the input for BELL characters, it may still beep. This is due to font settings and unicode conversion. The character in question is [U+2022](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm), Bullet.

Raymond Chen [explains](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/01/04/1411080.aspx):

> In the OEM code page, the bullet character is being converted to a
>   beep. But why is that?
>
> What you're seeing is MB_USEGLYPHCHARS in reverse. Michael Kaplan
>   discussed MB_USEGLYPHCHARS a while ago. It determines whether certain
>   characters should be treated as control characters or as printable
>   characters when converting to Unicode. For example, it controls
>   whether the ASCII bell character 0x07 should be converted to the
>   Unicode bell character U+0007 or to the Unicode bullet U+2022. You
>   need the MB_USEGLYPHCHARS flag to decide which way to go when
>   converting to Unicode, but there is no corresponding ambiguity when
>   converting from Unicode. When converting from Unicode, both U+0007 and
>   U+2022 map to the ASCII bell character.