# Why is my console application beeping?

Tags: c#, console-application

At first I thought maybe characters are being rendered into a beep, as that seems to be the common one on google. But I just noticed if I let it keep going for over 30 seconds, and then close the app my computers still beeping like mad for several more seconds. Now I'm scared. Can beeping signal something bad is happening? What should I look for?

Thanks

Edit

The beep is coming out only when I run a certain part of my .exe. It keeps increasing in frequency over time quite rapidly. I am not using File.ReadAllText("binaryfile"), the messages at most are about 8/9 words!

More detail on the exe:
It uses zeroMQ to send between two apps. The first (one that seems to be the beeper) sends messages, the second replies and then the first writes the message to the console before sending a new message. It's a demonstration app at the moment and doesnt even send proper messages - just a number that starts at 0 and increases by 1 each loop iteration. It doesn't overflow, as i reset to zero if it gets too high.

Many thanks

Comment: state your question clearly is it hardware beep? or ?

Comment: I assume you do something like `Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText("binaryfile"))`. That can make a lot of noise. Don't do that. See also [Why does my system beep when writing to Console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516800/why-does-my-system-beep-when-writing-to-console). It probably keeps going for a few seconds due to buffering.

Comment: In case it isn't obvious, you need to show your code within your question if you want any real help. People here are not fond of guessing games, which is all we have at the moment.

Comment: Sorry guys, I hope the edit helps

Comment: On WIndows, if Ctrl+C doesn't stop the noise soon enough, you can run `sc stop beep` from an elevated command prompt. `sc start beep` later to restart the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists an ASCII character called **BELL** (ASCII code 7) which, when printed on a terminal, causes the bell to ring. Nowadays, when printed to the Console window it causes the speaker to beep:

```
Console.WriteLine("\007");
```

So these beeps are caused by one of your `Console.Write*()` calls, which happen to send an ASCII 7 hidden among other stuff.

If you can't imagine which one causes the noise, I'd suggest some **Hard-Core-Debugging:**

Comment out one `Console.Write*()` after the next until the beeps go away.

A more clever strategy:

Comment out one half of all `Console.Write*()` and see if that helps. Comment out the other half if not. Iterate.

Comment: Thanks, seems it was a console write after all!